# Can not insert multiple entries into specific table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I have the following problem with an API in Entity Framework Core 2.2: I'm trying to save 3 records (details) to a table and it only stores one of them. I have done the same procedure several times and it works fine, but in this table it is only saving 1 record. My code is like this:

```
foreach (var i in details)
{
    var regDet = new table
        {
            campo1 = i.value1,
            campo2 = i.value2
        };

    dbcontext.table.Add(regDet);
}

await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: my guess would be that you add the same primarykey twice. or that in fact the foreach is only run once. but based on your example code it is hard to guess what's wrong here. it is also confusing that you have a foreach and never use the I.  please follow these guidelines: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and update your question

Comment: I edited the code, but that is not the issue.  I'm not sending the primary key value because it is an identity column.  Thanks for your response.

Comment: Making a debug to the code I could found it out that I'm sending 3 records but the last one is saved.

Comment: @DavidRuiz Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. It should clearly show that only one record is saved instead of three. Include the layout of your database tables as well, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query.

Answer (score -1):

Your issued is most likely caused by reuse of the `regDet` variable within the `foreach` loop.

The compiler is actually going to modify your foreach to function slightly differently than you expect. Ultimately your loop will behave as if it were written like this:

```
Table regDet;
foreach (var i in details)
{
    regDet = new table
        {
            campo1 = i.value1,
            campo2 = i.value2
        };

    dbcontext.table.Add(regDet);
}

await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Writing the loop in this way can help emphasize the problem. We are overwriting the `regDet` variable with new values before calling `dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();`

With that in mind, there are two ways this can be fixed.

1. Omit the variable.

```
foreach (var i in details)
{
    dbcontext.table.Add(new table
        {
            campo1 = i.value1,
            campo2 = i.value2
        });
}

await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

2. Move `dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();` into the `foreach` loop.

```
foreach (var i in details)
{
    var regDet = new table
        {
            campo1 = i.value1,
            campo2 = i.value2
        };

    dbcontext.table.Add(regDet);
    await dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

Comment: I did both examples, but it only saved one record.